# how to protect a make target against concurrent execution?

Tags: makefile

What is the simplest way to make sure that

```
make target
```

does not run concurrently ? If two process run `make target` at the same time, both would run the target and will likely step on each other toes.

A shell snippet such as

```
dotlockfile target.lock || exit 1
trap "dotlockfile -u target.lock" EXIT
make target
```

works well: if two process run that snippet at the same time, one of them will acquire the lock and the other will wait for it to finish. When the first process completes, the other get to run `make target` which will return immediately and do nothing because the target has already been built.

I'm hoping there is a simpler way to do the same thing.

Comment: "Simpler" is awfully subjective.

Answer (score 0):

The following (in your makefile) should significantly reduce the probability that several processes collide:

```
target:
    @if [ -f making.target ]; then \
        echo "Already making target..."; \
        exit 1; \
    else \
        touch making.target; \
        <do whatever is needed to make target>; \
        rm making.target; \
    fi
```

You can easily test it by replacing `<do whatever is needed to make target>` by `sleep 10` and try to `make target` twice, with and without waiting for the first one when launching the second. Note that you can also simply skip the recipe instead of aborting the whole make run: simply remove the `exit 1` line.

Comment: This leaves a window of opportunity for the problem to happen. And it is unfortunately more complicated than the solution I currently have (which effectively protect against concurrent runs).

Comment: _More complicated_: yes and no. It relies on make only, which is a kind of simplification. But I agree that it is not yet simple and not 100% safe.

Answer (score 0):

The simpler solution is to use `flock` as follows:

```
flock /tmp/target.lock make target
```

If this command is run while another is holding the lock, it will wait for it to finish and will run when the lock is released. Alternatively, if the intention is to give up if a `make target` is already running, the `-n` flag can be used like so:

```
flock -n /tmp/target.lock make target
```